# GIT, not able to stage for commit

Tags: git

Inside my working directory I deleted an image.
The problem is, I'm not able to stage it for commit (add or remove).

```
$ git status
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

modified:   ...

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

deleted:    "public/images/logo-pb\357\200\242old.png"
```

Every time I try these commands (even with quotes):

```
git add public/images/logo-pb\357\200\242old.png
git rm public/images/logo-pb\357\200\242old.png
```

It always tells me:

```
fatal: pathspec 'public/images/logo-pb357200242old.png' did not match any files
```

Comment: Try `git add "public/images/logo-pb\357\200\242old.png"`

Comment: Try $ git checkout -- public/images/logo-pb\357\200\242old.png (reset the file to the original state) and then repeat process (delete file and stage delete for commit). The combination of slash+backslashes in path can be the problem.

Comment: What is meaning of those backslashes in `public/images/logo-pb\357\200\242old.png`? Are they supposed to be part of the filename? That's important because `public/images/logo-pb\357\200\242old.png`, if unquoted, will expand to `public/images/logo-pb357200242old.png`.

Comment: @Kleskowy the same error appears when I type "git checkout --". I think it's necessary to find the escape combination to match that filename.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What version of git you use? With my version (`1.9.4.msysgit.0`) I get for deleted `assembly.xml`:

```
C:\projects\Project\src\main\assembly>git add assembly.xml
warning: You ran 'git add' with neither '-A (--all)' or '--ignore-removal',
whose behaviour will change in Git 2.0 with respect to paths you removed.
Paths like 'src/main/assembly/assembly.xml' that are
removed from your working tree are ignored with this version of Git.

* 'git add --ignore-removal <pathspec>', which is the current default,
  ignores paths you removed from your working tree.

* 'git add --all <pathspec>' will let you also record the removals.

Run 'git status' to check the paths you removed from your working tree.
```

And when I run

```
git add -A assembly.xml
```

it doesn't complain anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but the issue might be with escaping '\' character. 
You should try the command

```
git add public/images/logo-pb\\357\\200\\242old.png
```

Answer (score 0):

`git rm $(git ls-files --deleted)` will help you as

`git ls-files --deleted` gives path to deleted files from  repository
and `git rm` will remove them.

Comment: Nope. Executing "git rm $(git ls-files --deleted)" says "fatal: pathspec '"public/images/logo-pb\357\200\242old.png"' did not match any files"